# Geometric morphisms and presheaves

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory, adjoint-functors

I would like concrete descriptions of the adjoint functors that arise in a geometric morphism induced by a functor between the base categories of categories of presheaves.

Suppose we have functor $F$ from a category $\mathbb{C}$ to a category $\mathbb{D}.$ Let $\mathbb{D}^{op}$ denote the opposite category to $\mathbb{D}.$ As usual we write $\textbf{Set}^{\mathbb{D}^{op}}$ to denote the category of presheaves on $\mathbb{D}.$ In this case, if I understand correctly, there will be a funtor $F^{*}$ from $\textbf{Set}^{\mathbb{D}^{op}}$ to $\textbf{Set}^{\mathbb{C}^{op}}$ which sends an object $\mathbb{D}^{op}\overset{X}{\rightarrow}\textbf{Set}$ of $\textbf{Set}^{\mathbb{D}^{op}}$ to the precomposition $\mathbb{C}^{op}\overset{X\circ F^{op}}{\longrightarrow}\textbf{Set}.$ Also $F^{*}$ sends an arrow $X\overset{\alpha}{\rightarrow}Y$ of $\textbf{Set}^{\mathbb{D}^{op}}$ to the natural transformation $(X\circ F^{op})\overset{\beta}{\rightarrow}(Y\circ F^{op})$ with $\beta_{c}=\alpha_{F(c)}$ for each object $c$ of category $\mathbb{C}.$

If I understand correctly from [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometric+morphism) then $F^{*}$ is part of an essential geometric morphism, and so there is a right adjoint $F_{*}$ of $F^{*}$ and there is a left adjoint $F_{!}$ of $F^{*}.$

My question is, how exactly do the functors $F_{*}$ and $F_{!}$ work on objects AND ON ARROWS ? Ideally I would like the answer to minimize the usage high level concepts, because I am quite inexperienced with adjoint functors and I do not know about Kan extensions.

Comment: To understand these functors is literally the same thing as to understand Kan extensions, so it's not really possible to talk about them without talking about Kan extensions.

Comment: As pointed out in the previous comment, these functors are known as Kan extensions.  For a more concrete formula, look at "pointwise Kan extensions": https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Kan+extension#Pointwise.

Comment: The most explicit formula that you will find in the general case is using coends, see for example "This is the (co-)end my only (co-)friend" by Loregian (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.02503.pdf). They can often be written down explicitly using certain equalizers. However, this is also a good source to learn about Kan extensions and doing very hands-on calculations with them, so feel free to study it :)